# how to add current login user to welcome.java

Tags: java, android, xml, sdk

i Have this Login Page so i need the cuurent login user to get display in welcome.java 
please and i need the curent user to be display in welcome .java file

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String LOGIN_URL =webservice/login.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
        ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        // setup input fields
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        // setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        // register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    // save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", username);
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you mean private static final String LOGIN_URL ="webservice/login.php"; ?

Comment: What do you mean by Welcome.java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly mean. Do you want to display the last successful user to the login prompt?

It looks like it is saved in the shared preferences with the key `"user"`. (See code following the "json success tag" comment).

```
// setup input fields
user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String userName = sp.getString("user", "");
user.setText(userName);

pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Comment: thanks but i want to display a welcome page when the user is logged in